# Create a link to a Web Forms page and send some variables to it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a Web Forms page in my ASP.NET MVC application. I need to create a link to it, but `ActionLink` needs a controller/action pair, which the page doesn't have.

How do I create a link to send variables (a string and an int) to a .aspx page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from constructing a 'normal' link with plain old HTML:

```
`<a href="page.aspx?id=<%:Model.Id %>&amp;query=<%:Model.query%>">my link</a>`
```